# jqgrid odd even row color

Tags: jquery, css, json, jqgrid

When I apply style class `myAltRowClass`to change alternate `colors` for jqgrid `odd even row`. left, right and bottom borders are in black color.

I want to apply `odd even row color` for `all jqgrids` through `css`

**The grid looks like below screenshot**.

[image: oddevenproblem]

When used below code in `loadComplete` function this problem is not occurred

```
$("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#E0E0E0");
```

**jqgrid looks like below screenshot**.

[image: oddevenrow]

**Css Class**

```
.myAltRowClass {
    background: #E0E0E0;
}
```

**Code:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
            //jqGrid
            $("#usersList").jqGrid({
                url:'<%=request.getContextPath() %>/Admin/getAllUsersList',
                datatype: "json",               
                colNames:['Edit','First Name','Middle Name','LastName','Mobile Number','Active'],
                colModel:[
                    {name:'userId',search:false,index:'userId',width:30,sortable: false,formatter: editLink},                       
                    {name:'firstName',index:'firstName', width:100},
                    {name:'middleName',index:'middleName', width:100},
                    {name:'lastName',index:'lastName', width:100},
                    {name:'mobileNo',index:'user.mobileNo', width:100},
                    {name:'isActive',index:'user.isActive',width:80},
                    ],
                    rowNum:20,
                    rowList:[10,20,30,40,50],
                    rownumbers: true,  
                    pager: '#pagerDiv',
                    sortname: 'user.primaryEmail',  
                    viewrecords: true,  
                    sortorder: "asc",

                    loadComplete: function() {
                        //$("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#E0E0E0");

                        $("tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass('myAltRowClass');
                    },

            });
            $('#gridContainer div:not(.ui-jqgrid-titlebar)').width("100%");
            $('.ui-jqgrid-bdiv').css('height', window.innerHeight * .65);
            $('#load_usersList').width("130");
            $("#usersList").jqGrid('navGrid','#pagerDiv',{edit:false,add:false,del:false},{},{},{}, {closeAfterSearch:true});
            $(".inline").colorbox({inline:true, width:"20%"});
        });

        function editLink(cellValue, options, rowdata, action)
        {
            return "<a href='<%=request.getContextPath()%>/Admin/editUser/" + rowdata.userId + "' class='ui-icon ui-icon-pencil' ></a>";
        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/CustomAltRowColors.htm) demonstrates how to define CSS rules and set the rules to odd and even rows of the grid. The code used in the demo

```js
loadComplete: function () {
    $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass("myAltRowClassEven");
    $(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:even").addClass("myAltRowClassOdd");
}
```

It's important to understand that jqGrid use first *hidden* row in the grid to set the column widths. So one have to use jQuery [:even](https://api.jquery.com/even-selector/) selector to set class on **odd** rows and one have to use [:odd](https://api.jquery.com/odd-selector/) selector to set class on **even** rows.

The CSS rules which I used in the demo are the following

```css
.myAltRowClassEven { background: #E0E0E0; border-color: #79B7E7; color: Tomato; }
.myAltRowClassOdd { background: DarkOrange; }
.ui-state-hover.myAltRowClassEven { color: Magenta; }
.ui-state-hover.myAltRowClassOdd { color: RoyalBlue; }
.ui-state-highlight.myAltRowClassEven { color: PaleGreen; }
.ui-state-highlight.myAltRowClassOdd { color: Sienna; }
```

As the result one get very multicolored picture like with different colors or background colors for odd/even/hovered/selected rows:

[image]

The colors looks terrible. I wanted just demonstrates how one customize there.

Answer (score 0):

Added the `border-color: #79B7E7` in `myAltRowClass`. jqgrid odd row background color is changed without borders.

```
.myAltRowClass {
   background: #E0E0E0;
   border-color: #79B7E7;
}
```

Comment: it's clear that `background-color` and `border-color` (or `border-bottom-color` used by jqGrid [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.6.0/css/ui.jqgrid.css#L38)) are different. You can just extend CSS settings which you use either for `.myAltRowClass` or `$("tr.jqgrow:odd").css({background: "#E0E0E0", "border-color": "#79B7E7"});`. The CSS rule for `background-color` can don't work depend on jQuery UI Theme which one use because of background image. `background: #E0E0E0;` removes `background-image` of jQuery UI Theme. So the color will be safe shown.

Comment: @Oleg for applying odd row even row color in jqgrid in entire project I called `myAltRowClass` class. if I use `$("tr.jqgrow:odd").css({background: "#E0E0E0", "border-color": "#79B7E7"});` this format I update on every screen where jqgrid is used.

Comment: If you do this in `loadComplete` then you should of cause use `this`: `$(this).find(">tbody>tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass("myAltRowClass")`. Moreover you should define CSS rule for `myAltRowClass` with *more deep* cascading. For example `.ui-jqgrid .myAltRowClass {background: #E0E0E0;}` makes unneeded to use `.removeClass('ui-widget-content')`. I personally prefer to use just `.myAltRowClass {background: #E0E0E0;}`. In the case hovering of even rows works correctly and the row can be selected.

Comment: @Oleg can we change the `even row` color in jqgrid?.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean. jqGrid set it only if you use `altRows: true` and `altclass: "myAltRowClass"` options. You prefer to set the class manually. The color of the text can be set in `myAltRowClass` class. Try to use for example the following CSS rules: `.myAltRowClass { background: #E0E0E0; border-color: #79B7E7; color: red; } .ui-state-hover.myAltRowClass { color: Magenta; } .ui-state-highlight.myAltRowClass { color: PaleGreen; }`. The last two rules changes the color of text of even rows which are hovered or selected.

Comment: @Oleg I mean odd row background color is `background: #E0E0E0` and even row color is `white`. Can I change the `white` background color to some other color like `orange`.

Comment: I posted the demo in the answer. I hope it clear all above questions.