# How to set alternative row color and background color of jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-asp.net, mvcjqgrid

In jqgrid, i need below points to do:
 1. Set alternate row background color of jqgrid.
 2. Set Header background color of jqgrid.

Please share me which style i should add into my page or any jquery script to achieve  that ?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5553177/jqgrid-alternate-row-background

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19841588/jqgrid-change-background-color-of-grouping-header

Comment: tried,  `$(".ui-jqgrid tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background-color", "red");` , $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#FCF9E6");
but unable to change alternate row color. remain as it is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Previously asked question of mine [jqgrid odd even row color](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21906215/1624035) solves your problem for changing jqgrid background color.

**Step: 1**
Change column background color in jqgrid using css

```
loadComplete: function() {
    $("tr.jqgrow:odd").css("background", "#E0E0E0");
},
```

**Step: 2**
Change `header color` of `jqgrid` use below css class.

```
.ui-th-column, .ui-jqgrid .ui-jqgrid-htable th.ui-th-column {
    border-bottom: 0 none;
    border-top: 0 none;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background: orange;
}
```